# Plot vtk file using Python

Tags: spyder, vtk

I cannot display a vtk file using python. Spyder Code Analysis prompts me that vtkDataSetMapper is an undefined name.

I know the vtk file is in order because I have already displayed it using Paraview.

My vtk file looks like this:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
 velocity field
 ASCII
 DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
 DIMENSIONS         108         103          31
 ORIGIN   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       -297.50000000000000     
 SPACING   15.465818554775332        12.565027060488859        10.000000000000000     
 POINT_DATA      344844
 SCALARS scalars float
 LOOKUP_TABLE default
 8.4405251
 8.4405251
...
...
...
```

After the last shown line, the vtk file contains the rest of information, which are merely numbers (~ 300000 values)

My code looks like this:

```
import vtk

# Read vtk file data 
reader = vtk.vtkDataSetReader()
reader.SetFileName("seaust.vtk")
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()  # Activate the reading of all scalars
reader.ReadAllVectorsOn()  # Activate the reading of all vectors
reader.ReadAllTensorsOn()  # Activate the reading of all tensors
reader.Update()
data = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_range = data.GetScalarRange()

# Create the mapper that corresponds the objects of the vtk file
# into graphics elements
mapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInput(data)
```

When trying to compile the code, python prompts me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'vtkRenderingCorePython.vtkDataSetMapper' object has no attribute 'SetInput'
```

I'm expecting a 3D visualisation of my data.

Can you please help me to get it?

Comment: See VTK examples. https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/.

Also python code do not "compile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the vtk. in 
`mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()`

and you probably need to use
`mapper.SetInputData(data)`