# plot vtk using python

Tags: python, vtk, openfoam

I'm using python to plot a VTK data. I'm following this example: [http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD_2007/presentation_rasmus.pdf](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/%7Ehani/kurser/OS_CFD_2007/presentation_rasmus.pdf) and I'm using the same OpenFOAM tutorial elbow, with exactly the same archive elbow_200.vtk.

If I copy the code as it is, I got the error:
AttributeError: 'vtkmodules.vtkFiltersCore.vtkFieldDataToAttributeD' object has no attribute 'SetInput'

Then I see that: https://vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a01389.html#z1879_2 and realized that I have only SetInputFieldToDataObjectField.

I tried...

```
import os
from vtk import *
from vtk import vtkUnstructuredGridReader

#set the fileName for the current case
myFileName='elbow_200.vtk'

#Need a reader for unstructured grids
reader = vtkUnstructuredGridReader()

reader.SetFileName(myFileName)

reader.Update()

#In OpenFOAM all results are Field-data.
#This has no concept of cells or nodes.
#Need to filter to cells.


toCellFilter = vtkFieldDataToAttributeDataFilter()
toCellFilter.SetInputFieldToDataObjectField()
toCellFilter.SetInputFieldToCellDataField() #celulas
toCellFilter.SetOutputAttributeDataToCellData() 

#Assign here which field
#we are interested in.
toCellFilter.SetScalarComponent(0, 'alpha.air' ,0)
#This is all we need to do do calculations.
#To get 3D image, need some more components.
#First a window

renWin = vtkRenderWindow()

ren1 = vtkRenderer()
#Add renderer to window
renWin.AddRenderer(ren1)
#Add pressure data to the renderer.

#Mapping assigns data to colors and geometry.
mapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInputData(toCellFilter.GetOutput())


#The object is assigned to an actor.
actor = vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
#Add actor to renderer.
ren1.AddActor(actor)
#Finally render image
renWin.Render()
```

Using the code above, I got this error:

2022-08-23 13:32:32.842 ( 831.111s) [        8238F740]       vtkExecutive.cxx:752    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x560cb23f6a40): Algorithm vtkFieldDataToAttributeDataFilter(0x560cb22945b0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (0x560cb23f50b0)
Debug: Off
Modified Time: 1445
Reference Count: 1
Registered Events: (none)
Request: REQUEST_DATA_OBJECT
ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0

2022-08-23 13:32:32.920 ( 831.189s) [        8238F740]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:666    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x560cb23fe960): Input port 0 of algorithm vtkDataSetMapper(0x560cb2368110) has 0 connections but is not optional.
2022-08-23 13:32:32.920 ( 831.189s) [        8238F740]vtkDemandDrivenPipeline:666    ERR| vtkCompositeDataPipeline (0x560cb23fe960): Input port 0 of algorithm vtkDataSetMapper(0x560cb2368110) has 0 connections but is not optional.

I tried this [Plot vtk file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001639/plot-vtk-file-using-python) with no success..

Answer (score 1):

The PDF presentation is of a very old version of VTK, where functions like `SetInput()` still existed. In the meantime, a lot has changed regarding how you create the VTK pipeline, see [here](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/New_Pipeline) for example. I guess you are using a more recent version of VTK.

My guess is that you have to change the line (from the original code from the presentation)

```
toCellFilter.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())
```

to the line

```
toCellFilter.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
```

and it should work.

Your code right now simply cannot work, because you don't give an input to your `vtkFieldDataToAttributeDataFilter`. That's also what the error output is trying to tell you: `Algorithm vtkFieldDataToAttributeDataFilter(0x560cb22945b0) returned failure for request: vtkInformation`. This means that the filter can't find its input, it doesn't get the `vtkInformation` object from the input.

Comment: The error has gone. Although, I can't see the resulting image. There is a window that opens and closes instantly after I run the python code...

Comment: That's because you didn't use a `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` in your script, so the window won't stay open.
I suggest that you look up a basic tutorial for VTK with python.